# ASP.NET Core Web API with Azure AD auth and BASIC auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, .net-6.0

I have created a .NET6 Web-API that will be consumed by an SPA. I have these projects all set up with Azure AD auth and it's working great.

In my Web-API I now want to have a controller that can be accessed with BASIC Auth. What is the best aproach here?

I have tried creating a custom auth attribute like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class BasicAuth : Attribute, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null)
        {
            var auth = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(auth))
            {
                if (IsValidToken(auth))
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidToken(string auth)
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

        string base64 = auth.Split(" ")[1];

        var cred = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));

        var credArray = cred.Split(':');

        if (credArray[0] == "username" && credArray[1] == "password")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then i put the attribute like this:

```
[BasicAuth]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PublicDataController : ControllerBase{...}
```

This is working but I have a feeling that it can be done better?

Any advice?

Comment: if you configure azure ad correctly and spa/api your authorization middleware would deal with [Authorize] for you, it would only be when you need granular Authorization where you need to use Policies, you certainly dont need to manually parse the headers like that